# Time taken to Download Image from URL and Get File Size

Tags: php

I'm creating an image analyzer that will tell the time required to download an image and say the file size of the image.

Input: http://www.inforge.in/ongoing-works/main_project/img/profile1.png

Output: Time taken to download: 1 second
        File size: 2 KB

```
<?php
$starttime = microtime(true);
    $img = get_headers("http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2564.jpg", 1);
    print $img["Content-Length"];
$stoptime  = microtime(true);
$time = ($stoptime - $starttime);
?>
```

The above code can get file size. But the time taken will be time only to get HTTP headers. I need the time took to download the image too. How can i do that?

Comment: you will also need to consider the users internet connection speed.

Comment: @roullie this code will be put on my server. So users will not be affected